# Morris donut chart with dynamic json data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, donut-chart

I'm using morris donuy chart and I'm not able to pass my json array data to the jquery corectly I think. Here is my php file:

```
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("Select COUNT(Incasari.id_produs) as cnt,Incasari.id_produs,denumire_produs from Incasari
                    INNER JOIN Produse on Produse.id_produs=Incasari.id_produs Group By Incasari.id_produs order by cnt desc limit 3 ");
$stmt->execute();

while ($row=$stmt->fetch())
{
    $arr[]= array(
        'id'   => ''.$row['id_produs'].'',
        'denumire'   => ''.$row['denumire_produs'].'',
        'cnt'  => ''.$row['cnt'].''
    );

}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

The returned result is:

```
[{"id":"3","denumire":"bere","cnt":"5"},
 {"id":"1","denumire":"Suc","cnt":"3"},
 {"id":"2","denumire":"pepsi","cnt":"2"}]
```

And the javascript part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'app/chart_produse.php', // getchart values
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {get_values: true},
        success: function(response) {
            var donut = new Morris.Donut({
                element: 'sales-chart',
                resize: true,
                colors: ["#3c8dbc", "#f56954", "#00a65a"],
                data: response,
                hideHover: 'auto'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your format of passing data is not right.http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/donuts.html
 According to Moris donut documentation 

 The data to plot. This is an array of objects, containing `label` and
 `value` attributes corresponding to the labels and sizes of the  segments of the donut chart.

Comment: true, thnx i change the format and it's working, you can add as a response to accept it if you want

Comment: The above code is your solution @chris227?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format of passing data is not right.http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/donuts.html
 According to Moris donut documentation

> The data to plot. This is an array of objects, containing `label` and
>   `value` attributes corresponding to the labels and sizes of the segments
>   of the donut chart.